# How to programmatically(C#) go to a certain keyframe in a silverlight animation?

Tags: c#, silverlight, animation

Is there a way of going to a certain keyframe inside of a silverlight animation? For example the user clicks a button and it goes to the specified keyframe in the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use seek method in the storyboard.

```
myStoryboard.Begin();
myStoryboard.Seek(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3));
```

Here is some reference [Storyboard.Seek Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190534%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)